# How to construct booleans and access them with java/oracle stored proc

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, database

First time using Oracle, normally use SQLServer, and ran into a curious issue.
I was tearing my hair out with this problem, and trying random things and one happened to work.

So originally, I had only two parameters, and everything worked fine. I then wished to add a boolean value to allow for multiple paths in my stored proc. I test it out in my db environment, and there are no errors and I get back the data I expect. I then add the few lines in my java code to pull this data, and suddenly I get "`wrong number or types of parameters`" error.

After trying several things, I simply change the type in Oracle from Boolean to Int, leaving the java code still as "`setBoolean(3, true)`" and everything works.

So my questions are:

1) what am I sending with this setBoolean() on the java side, and what is Oracle getting?

2) what was it expecting before when it was of type "`Boolean`, and why is this not compatible with `setBoolean()`?"

3) Should I use Oracle type int with java setBoolean(), or some other combination such as Oracle Varchar, and setString(), when going for speed?

**Java:**

```
String jobquery =   "{call PKG_TEST.GET_PLAN_DATA(?,?,?)}";  
            CallableStatement callStmt = con.prepareCall(jobquery);

            callStmt.setString(1,"15105");
            callStmt.setString(2, "");
            callStmt.setBoolean(3, true);
```

**Oracle SP(previous):**

```
PROCEDURE GET_PLAN_DATA(
        NAME_N_IN IN VARCHAR2,
        TYPE_C_IN IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
        ONLY_RESTRICTIONS_IN IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE)
```

**Oracle changed to:**

```
 PROCEDURE GET_PLAN_DATA(
            NAME_N_IN IN VARCHAR2,
            TYPE_C_IN IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
            ONLY_RESTRICTIONS_IN IN INT DEFAULT 0)
```

Comment: You might want to read this: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=611049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1) what am I sending with this setBoolean() on the java side, and what is Oracle getting?*

From the Java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29):

`Sets the designated parameter to the given Java boolean value. The driver converts this to an SQL BIT value when it sends it to the database.`

So the `Boolean` value is converted into a `BIT` value.

*2) what was it expecting before when it was of type `Boolean`, and why is this not compatible with setBoolean()?"*

As said, it converts it into a `BIT` value, so it was expecting the same thing. Before, there existed a `Boolean` variable for oracle too. But as you said,*After trying several things, I simply change the type in Oracle from Boolean to Int, leaving the java code still as "setBoolean(3, true)" and everything works.*, reason being, oracle doesn't have boolean variable any more. Why? Read [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:6263249199595) for a deep discussion on the issue.

*3) Should I use Oracle type int with java setBoolean(), or some other combination such as Oracle Varchar, and setString(), when going for speed?*

I would say `varchar` and `setString()`. Reason, `setString()` method [converts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) it into a `varchar`. Hence, you save time as compared to `setBoolean()` and `int`, where you go from `Boolean` to `BIT` to `int`.

---

**EDIT**

Just something copy pasted from one of the above mentioned links to clarify the matter more:

Hi Tom,
I have a question regarding boolean datatype.

Below is the SP, written by our client and we need to integrate this with our application.

```
PROCEDURE sp_xxxx_map (
                ic_opt_number       IN  VARCHAR2,
                in_cast_number    IN  NUMBER,
                in_tyre_amount          IN  NUMBER,
                ob_is_valid             OUT BOOLEAN,
                ob_is_obgr_obgt_valid   OUT BOOLEAN,
```

--------------- few more parameters....

While integrating the above, everything id fine except boolean OUT parameter.
I think(correct me if am wrong) there is no SQL datatype in java(JDBC classes) to catch the
"ob_is_valid", "ob_is_obgr_obgt_valid" parameters.
How do can go about this issue.
One idea is:
Can I write another SP(say SP1), which will call the above SP and will convert the boolean types to 
CHARs like 'Y' for true and 'N' for false.
Finally I let the application to call the newly created SP1.

Followup   February 5, 2003 - 9am Central time zone:

just prepare and execute:

```
declare
   b1 boolean;
   b2 boolean;
   n1 number := 0;
   n2 number := 0; 
begin
   sp_xxxx_map( ?, ?, ?, b1, b2 );
   if (b1) then n1 := 1; end if;
   if (b2) then n2 := 1; end if;
   ? := n1;
   ? := n2;
end;
```

from the jdbc app.

Comment: I'm confused about your answer to #2: "As said, it converts it into a BIT value, so it was expecting the same thing." If the driver converts it to a SQL BIT value, what is a Oracle BOOLEAN value expecting? Y/N or "true"/"false"? To elaborate, what could I send in my callStmt.set to leave the Oracle variable as Boolean, and it still work?

Comment: @KazekageGaara- Oracle **has** a boolean datatype but only for PLSQL and not SQL

Comment: @A.B.Cade the questions is specific to SQL,so the answer was in the light of the same.

Comment: @JWiley Oracle doesn't support Boolean,when you are concerned with SQL. You will have to do away with boolean as your oracle variable.

Comment: So when I say ONLY_RESTRICTIONS_IN IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE, it's creating a custom variable? I can execute this sp locally, with no issue, and it lets me uncheck/check it, with both paths working....

Comment: Did you even go through the links I have provided?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm still not seeing an explanation about how it works locally as a boolean but won't communicate with java.

Comment: Kindly see the edit. It has been copy pasted from one of the links, addressing a specific issue,somewhat similar to yours. Please go through that link as it addresses many such issues.

Comment: Yes, I saw that mapping. It's not clarifying my question, it's just showing another example for a solution. I'm looking for more of a "why". I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Well that forum is an official oracle forum. If there isn't a why there, I probably guess the why would be tough to find. You can wait maybe,one of the experts here might come up with better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean are not supported in Stored Procedure input 
It is a known limitation of the JDBC driver

> The JDBC drivers do not support the passing of BOOLEAN parameters to
>   PL/SQL stored procedures.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/apxtblsh.htm#i1005380